Could Android use disk space to queue a SQLite transaction?
I would like to make a huge transaction with Androidx Room, something like the following:
@Transaction
fun addGeneratedRows() {
  for (i in 0 until 5_000_000) {
    addItem(generateRowWhichTakesUpALotOfMemory())
  }
}
@Insert fun addItem(itm: MyLargeRow) 

Now, I am worried this may lead to an Out of Memory error if Room will store the entire transaction in RAM before writing it to the database.
But I can imagine it might buffer the rows onto disk, allowing the garbage collector to purge the object in between the passes of for, since they are generated on the fly.
Well, will it? I cannot seem to find a source that it does, but also no source that it definitely does not.

Without having it thoroughly tested, I'm pretty this won't be a problem for the database. Room relies on the transaction mechanism of SQLite which in turn writes a journal of all changes to disk so it can (almost) instantly atomically either commit or roll back the entire transaction. How much and which parts of the journal is managed in memory I'm not sure about, but I'm pretty sure the raw data is already written to disk during the loop.
With your code you could probably quite easily test this by adding another 0 to the number of entries and look at the free memory of the device when you run this.

I believe that you are more likely to encounter a DISK FULL error then an out of memory (as per testing undertaken, see log extracts below).
However, first things first. Room in it's wisdom will not run the body of the addGeneratedRows within a transaction. Each individual addItem invocation will be a transaction.  You can fool Room into running them in a single transaction by making the function an @Query that queries nothing by using:-
@Transaction
@Query("")
fun addGeneratedRows ....

This will then, if there is a failure issue (these examples when trying to add 5,000,000 largish rows):-
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: a.a.so78414239kotlinroomoomtest, PID: 25860
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.a.so78414239kotlinroomoomtest/a.a.so78414239kotlinroomoomtest.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteFullException: database or disk is full (code 13 SQLITE_FULL)

instead of (i.e. without the dummy @Query):-
E/SQLiteLog: (13) statement aborts at 16: [INSERT OR ABORT INTO `MyLargeRow` (`id`,`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)] database or disk is full
E/SQLiteLog: (1) statement aborts at 1: [ROLLBACK;] cannot rollback - no transaction is active

Testing
The following code was used for testing:-
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao=db.getAllDAOs()
        dao.addItem(MyLargeRow(null,ByteArray(0),"First",""))
        dao.addGeneratedRows(5_000_000,100,100)
        dao.addItem(MyLargeRow(null,ByteArray(0),"Last",""))
    }
}

@Database(entities = [MyLargeRow::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs
    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance= Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
@Entity
data class MyLargeRow(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long?=null,
    var col1: ByteArray,
    var col2: String,
    var col3: String
)
@Dao
interface AllDAOs{

    @Transaction
    @Query("") /* <<<<<<<<<< ADDED >>>>>>>>>>*/
    fun addGeneratedRows(rowsToAdd:Int=100,baSize:Int=100,c2Size:Int=100) {
        for (i in 0 until /*5_000_000*/ rowsToAdd) {
            addItem(generateRowWhichTakesUpALotOfMemory())
        }
    }
    @Insert fun addItem(itm: MyLargeRow)

    /* Made up */
    fun generateRowWhichTakesUpALotOfMemory(baSize: Int = 100, c2Size: Int = 100): MyLargeRow {
        val baseString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        val ba: ArrayList<Byte> = arrayListOf()
        for (i in 1..baSize) {
            ba.add(abs(Random.nextInt()).toByte())
        }
        val sb=StringBuilder()
        for (i in 1..c2Size) {
            val c = baseString.get((abs(Random.nextInt()) % baseString.length))
            for (o in 1..((Random.nextInt() % 10) + 1)) {
                sb.append(c)
            }
        }
        return MyLargeRow(null,ba.toByteArray(),sb.toString(),sb.toString())
    }
}


The 2nd run (actually first but reported 2nd) had the @Query("") commented out.
as can be seen the functions utilise parameters which allows the invocation to control the sizes.

Test/Run 3 5002
If the test is run with 5000 rows as per dao.addGeneratedRows(5_000,100,100) then there is no failure and the database via App inspection:-


note the first row

.... and:-

Using Device File Explorer:-

Test/Run 4 500000 rows
This failed with disk full.
Test/Run 5 100000 rows
This worked with Device File Explorer showing:-

Factors/Considerations
Each device will have it's own limits.
With SQLite the DISK_FULL can be caused by exceeding the highest allowable value (9223372036854775807) for the id. This can be artificially introduced/forced IF AUTOINCREMENT is used and an id were set close to or at the limit. As AUTOINNCRMENT is a constraint that results in the auto generation of the id value being greater than any ever used id value (for the table). The code above avoids the use of AUTOINCREMENT (autoGenerate=false).
It might not actually be the database file itself but the temporary underlying files, perhaps the -wal file. You may find https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html interesting/useful.
As for memory Android Studio's Profiler, when utilised, for the above testing produced consistent results.

Always close to but under 32Mb of memory when running, around 20% CPU and less than medium Energy being utilised. Here's the latest snapshot:-



The noticeable change/spike is around when the inserts finished.


You may wish to consider:-

SQLite uses dynamic memory allocation to obtain memory for storing various objects (ex: database connections and prepared statements) and to build a memory cache of the database file and to hold the results of queries. Much effort has gone into making the dynamic memory allocation subsystem of SQLite reliable, predictable, robust, secure, and efficient.


https://www.sqlite.org/malloc.html

